# Oracle Migrate Data from 1 Env to Another in commandline

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, data-migration

I'm trying to migrate the Data from my One instance of Oracle 11g Server to another. For normal scenario, I'll use the SQLDeveloper and export the database.

But in current scenario, i'm not allowed to use SQLDeveloper and can access the Oracle DB only using CommandLine SqlPlus.

Can someone advice how to migrate data from one oracle 11g server to another using commandline?

Comment: so you want to export data from oracle server and import it to another one right ?>

Comment: Right Moudiz. I need to do that

Comment: its been a while for me since I used oracle data pump , but try this link https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g

Comment: Definitely data pump. This is exactly what it's designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Data Pump is probably the best solution for this task. If you want to export the entire database, the command would look something like this:

```
expdp [USER]/[PASS]@[DATABASE] full=Y directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=DataBaseExport.dmp logfile=DataPumpLog.log
```

More info can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#i1006388